# How do I put more than one pi on my network

Tags: networking, hardware

as you can probably tell from my stupid question I am a rank beginner with the raspberry pi.  I am very keen however as I am the proud owner of 5 raspberry pi 4's and 4 Rapsberry pi 5's (I am yet to track down the 27W ps the 5 requires I am in australia and not only do things take a while to get here, but the suppliers tend to keep stock levels low).  All 9 pi's are 8GB.

Why so many Pi's?  I thought they each could only run a couple of things on each.  I didnt know about docker, or for that matter kubernetes!!

THe state of play.

I figured the best way to learn about stuff is from the youtubes.  I am a bit of a Network chuck and Jeff geering fanboy (although I do worry about how much damn coffee Chuck drinks).  So far I have managed to flash the OS, update and upgrade the OS.  I have worked out how to login without using a password using public and private keys get a static address and I have managed to install docker.  I have manage to pull a couple of images.  I have not managed to install docker compose.  I did manage to boot from an ssd drive.

I run the raspberry Pis on a headless setup in command line in powershell

All this work was done in an rpi4.  I thought I would try one of my RPi5's and and although I flashed the OS with a different local host (JohnsLab2), it came up with the same local host as the RPi4 (JohnsLab1) and although I took care to put in the password for RPi5, it would not let me log in.

If you are still with me, my question is.... I want to set up another static address for my RPi5 as it is also destined to be a server.  How do I do this?  is this a question of configuring the RPi5 to use a different ethernet port?

Comment: I can suggest one solution to your problem. I don't know how you managed to get so many Pi5 - none of the Australian authorised resellers have stock and limit purchases to a single unit. Send me one and I will happily help.

Comment: If you are assigning static addresses you are missing the whole point of networking. Windows and MacOS users don't do this. I have 9 Pi (of different types) not a static address in sight.

Comment: most of your post is irrelevant fluff ... first four paragraphs are not relevant to the question ... please reduce the wording of your post

Comment: *"static address ... destined to be a server""* -> Don't do it that way.  Get all the hostnames set for different `foo.local` hosts and use [Avahi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software)), an mDNS implementation; it runs by default (`systemctl status avahi-daemon`, `lsof -i UDP:5353`) and corresponding software is also default on most other devices/smartphones/laptops etc.

Comment: I got my RPi 5's through ali baba.... they cost me $200aud for BOTH of them  I ordered them in mid Nov and they were here just in time for christmas

Comment: THanks for the offer milliways, but I would rather get help from someone a little less mercenary than yourself